# segue from two different viewControllers osx swift

Tags: macos, swift, segue, nstableview

I'm writing an app that uses tab view controller (each tab has own view controller) and I want to display results of calculations in two tables in the same table view. I connected that table view to both viewControllers with sagues. The problem I have is every time I open table view declaration of arrays makes both of them empty and only one table displays like I want it to. Is there a way to resolve that?

Code from my Table View Controller

```
import Cocoa

class TableView: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var ResultsTable: NSTableView!

    @IBOutlet var ResultTableInvers: NSTableView!

    var rekord : [(fi1: String, lambda1: String, fi2: String, lambda2: String, A12: String, A21: String, s: String)] = []
    var rekordInverse : [(fi1: String, lambda1: String, fi2: String, lambda2: String, A12: String, A21: String, s: String)] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println(rekord)
        self.ResultsTable.reloadData()
        self.ResultTableInvers.reloadData()
        // Do view setup here.
    }


    @IBAction func powrot(sender: NSButton) {

        dismissViewController(self)
    }



    func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        if(tableView == self.ResultsTable){
            return self.rekord.count
        } else { return self.rekordInverse.count}



    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject? {
         var newString = ""
          var myArray : [(fi1: String, lambda1: String, fi2: String, lambda2: String, A12: String, A21: String, s: String)] = []
        if(tableView == self.ResultsTable){
        myArray = rekord
        } else { myArray = rekordInverse}


        switch (tableColumn!.identifier) {

        case "fi1":
            newString = myArray[row].fi1

        case "lambda1":
            newString = myArray[row].lambda1

        default: newString = "12"

        }

            return newString
    }


}
```